# Ember Data: A data hash was loaded ... but no primary key 'undefined' was provided

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use Ember Data to load a model.   The AJAX call to fetch the model seems to be successful but I get the following

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: A data hash was loaded for a model of type App.Account but no primary key 'undefined' was provided.
```

In ember-data.js:1128 it seems to be deferencing undefined for the primaryKey and not defaulting to 'id' when a model doesn't specify a primaryKey.   But I've also tried being explicit with the primaryKey to no effect.

For completeness, here is my model:

```
App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
    portfolio_id: DS.attr('integer'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    user_id: DS.attr('integer'),
    url: 'investment_account'
});
```

and I'm loading the account with the following:

```
App.store.find(App.Account, account_id)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem using -latest of both ember & ember-data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I "fixed" this by upgrading to the latest edge Ember Data (I was previously using both of the current distributions from both projects: 0.9.8.1 for ember.js and the four month old ember-data-latest.js on the ember-data github site).  I'm still using the same ember.js distribution but upgrading Ember Data seems to have resolved this.