# Ember data localStorage Adapter: find function throws error

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js

I am rolling a localStorage adaper for Ember data and when I run the find function, ie:

```
App.store.find(App.Person, 0 );
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: A data hash was loaded for a model of type App.Person but no primary key 'undefined' was provided.
```

At a more general level, I am a bit confused about the relationship between 'the persistent layer' ( in this case localStorage ) and the Ember Store. What does it mean to load something to the store? Does it mean an instance of DS.Person model is created with the data ?

Also, if you'll note I commented out a line 'App.store.didCreateRecord( model, data )' in the createRecord method since it, too is not working. What happens if I do not call store.didCreateRecord after the record has been loaded to localStorage.

The details:

```
DS.LocalStorageAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({

    get: Ember.get,
    set: Ember.set,

    createRecord: function( store, modelType, model ){
        var records, index, data;
        // get existing records of this model
        records = this.localStorage.get( modelType );
        index = records.length;
        data = this.get( model, 'data' );
        // set storageID of data
        data.set( 'storageID', index );

        // add data to existing records
        records[index] = data;
            // encode records
        records = JSON.stringify( records );
            // store records in localStorage
        this.localStorage.set( modelType, records );
        // App.store.didCreateRecord( model, data );

    },



    find: function( store, modelType, id ) {
        var records, model;
        records = this.localStorage.get( modelType );
        model = records[id];
        App.store.load( modelType, model );
    },

    localStorage: {
        set: function( modelType, value ){
            localStorage.setItem( modelType, value);
        },

        get: function( modelType ){
          var record = localStorage.getItem(modelType);
          record = JSON.parse(record) || [];
          return record;
        }

    }
});



//application model
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string', {key: 'css_name'}),
    storageID: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0, key: 'storageID'}),

});

//create a couple of records
App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {  ... } );
App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {  ... } );

//try and find one record
App.store.find(App.Person, 0);

error thrown:
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: A data hash was loaded for a model of type App.Person but    no primary key 'undefined' was provided. ember-latest.js:51
Ember.assert ember-latest.js:51
(anonymous function) ember-latest.js:131
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.load ember-data.js:1530
DS.LocalStorageAdapter.DS.Adapter.extend.find bookApp_1.js:111
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.findByClientId ember-data.js:1174
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.find ember-data.js:1140
findRecord webApplication.js:210
onclick
```

also please note this is similar to another question posted a bit ago:
[Ember Data: A data hash was loaded ... but no primary key 'undefined' was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871953/ember-data-a-data-hash-was-loaded-but-no-primary-key-undefined-was-provi)

though the answer there seems to not really explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Can give example of loading Fixture data for Ember 1.0 pre2

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "password": "password"
  }
];

App.User.find(1).get('email')
```

Works for me.

Comment: Oh yeah Ember data's changed so much since I posted this question I don't know if my question is still relevant :\  but Thanks for the answer and example though! :)